# Does CSS Media query prevent multiple requests?

Tags: css, httpwebrequest, media-queries

I'm trying to develop a simple mobile web site (only for ipad and HTC desire hd)
I tried to use css media query in order to change style sheets for different screen size , 
When I use firbug to see the requests , i noticed that there is an http request for each css file.
my expectation was that the request will be for accessed file only ,
any solution ?  .

Comment: "Does CSS Media query prevent multiple requests?" No.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both media query inside the css file.

For example:

```
@media screen and ()...{}
```

That way only one css file will be loaded, and the query will be inside different blocks of code.